# Is there a difference in the rear and front wheel track of the Suzuki Maruti Gypsy?

Tags: suzuki, maruti

https://auto.economictimes.indiatimes.com/cars/maruti-suzuki-gypsy/specs/king-soft-top-mpi

According to the website above, the width of a Suzuki Maruti Gypsy is 1540mm. However, there is no mention of the front or rear wheel tracks.

Is there a difference? Is the rear wider, or the front wider, or the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, a quick google search ([enter link description here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maruti_Gypsy)) gives wikipedia as the first link which has lots of information and states exactly what you look for:

Front track 1300mm

Rear track 1310mm

So, rear track is larger than front, a possibility mentioned by @Paulster2.

These values are based on the standard wheeel/tire combination, if an owner has changed wheels/tires then the track dimensions may be different.

An easy way to check is to use a piece of angle iron with two points on arms and a ruler.

Answer (score 1):

Most vehicles created with a single pair of wheels up front and a single set of wheels in the rear have the same wheel track (I could think of a few, like some Porsches have different wheel tracks ... and if a vehicle with dual rear tires, like a Silverado 3500 or Ford F350 have different front to rear wheel tracks). If they don't specify there's a difference, then it is a good assumption they are the same front/rear.